# how to use context in class which implements Screen?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, libgdx

i have a problem to use a database in libGdx, for use this first i create this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
{
    _db.execSQL(DataBaseClass.DATABASE_RECORD);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
{

    Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

    onCreate(_db);
}
}
```

and this class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DataBaseClass {

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my.database";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

static final String DATABASE_RECORD = "create table "+"RECORD"+
        "( " + "SCORE text, GAMES_PLAYED text); ";

public  SQLiteDatabase db;

private final Context context;

private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;


public DataBaseClass(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public DataBaseClass open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    return db;
}




public void updateGamesPlayed(String game) {

    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("GAMES_PLAYED", game);

    String where="GAMES_PLAYED = ?";
    db.update("RECORD",updatedValues, where, new String[]{game});
}


public void updateBestScore(String score) {

    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("SCORE", score);

    String where="SCORE = ?";
    db.update("RECORD",updatedValues, where, new String[]{score});
}
}
```

but when i call the DataBaseClass in my principal class, which implement the interface Screen, i have problem here:

```
DBClass = new DataBaseClass(CONTEXT);
```

what is the context in this class? i try to use: "this", "getContext()", getActivity","this.getActivity", etc... but nothing works.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Context here refers to your current class context you can simply pass `this` or `principal.this`

Comment: if i pass "this" or "principal.this" i need to change constructor to DataBaseClass

Comment: Why to change constructor of db class? your principle class is not extending Appcompact or Activity?

Comment: i try to create a game, my principal class implements Screen

Comment: You need to create a BaseActivity for your application from which you can get context anywhere where you extend it.